# Checking Value from Specific Column of dataframe and updating values from an array to Column 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with 2 columns in it Column A and Column B and an array of alphabets from A to P which are as follows

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({
'Column_A':[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1],
'Column_B':[]
})
```

the array is as follows:

```
    label = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P']
```

Expected output is

```
    'A':[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1],
'B':['A','A','A','A','A','E','E','E','E','E','I','I','I','I','I','M']
```

Value from Column B changes as soon as value from Column A is 1. and the  value is taken from the given array 'label'

I have tried using this for loop

```
    for row in df.index:   
         try:
              if df.loc[row,'Column_A'] == 1:
                   df.at[row, 'Column_B'] = label[row+4]
                   print(label[row])
              else:
                   df.ColumnB.fillna('ffill')
         except IndexError:
              row = (row+4)%4
              df.at[row, 'Coumn_B'] = label[row]
```

I also want to loopback if it reaches the last value in 'Label' Array.

Comment: Why just A, E , I and M are taken from the label?

Comment: Your code doesn't run.  Namely the creation of the sample dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some solution that should do the trick looks like:

```
label=list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP')
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Column_A': [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1],
'Column_B': label
})
```

Not exactly sure, what you intended with the fillna, because I think you don't need it.

```
max_index= len(label)
df['Column_B']='ffill'
lookup= 0
for row in df.index:
    if df.loc[row,'Column_A'] == 1:
       lookup= lookup+4 if lookup+4 < max_index else lookup%4
    df.at[row, 'Column_B'] = label[lookup]
    print(label[row])
```

I also avoid the exception handling in this case, because the "index overflow" can be handled without exception handling.

Btw. if you have a large dataframe you can probably make the code faster by eliminating one lookup (but you'd need to verify if it really runs faster). The solution would look like this then:

```
max_index= len(label)
df['Column_B']='ffill'
lookup= 0
for row, record in df.iterrows():
    if record['Column_A'] == 1:
       lookup= lookup+4 if lookup+4 < max_index else lookup%4
    df.at[row, 'Column_B'] = label[lookup]
    print(label[row])
```

Comment: Ok now I see, you originally meant fillna(method='ffill'). But I guess you would have had to call it after your loop, not in your loop.

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1

```
cond1 = df.Column_A == 1
cond2 = df.index == 0
mappr = lambda x: label[x]

df.assign(Column_B=np.where(cond1 | cond2, df.index.map(mappr), np.nan)).ffill()

    Column_A Column_B
0          0        A
1          0        A
2          0        A
3          0        A
4          0        A
5          1        F
6          0        F
7          0        F
8          0        F
9          0        F
10         1        K
11         0        K
12         0        K
13         0        K
14         0        K
15         1        P
```

---

#### Option 2

```
a = np.append(0, np.flatnonzero(df.Column_A))
b = df.Column_A.to_numpy().cumsum()
c = np.array(label)

df.assign(Column_B=c[a[b]])

    Column_A Column_B
0          0        A
1          0        A
2          0        A
3          0        A
4          0        A
5          1        F
6          0        F
7          0        F
8          0        F
9          0        F
10         1        K
11         0        K
12         0        K
13         0        K
14         0        K
15         1        P
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `groupby` with `transform` then `map`

```
df.reset_index().groupby(df.Column_A.eq(1).cumsum())['index'].transform('first').map(dict(enumerate(label)))
Out[139]: 
0     A
1     A
2     A
3     A
4     A
5     F
6     F
7     F
8     F
9     F
10    K
11    K
12    K
13    K
14    K
15    P
Name: index, dtype: object
```